# Kivy buildozer debug error :No module named kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build a simple kivy app with buildozer and python2 , but for some reason inside this build no module 'kivy'. And Some logs from buildozer :

```
[INFO]:    STDOUT:
    Using distutils 
Environ change use_sdl2 -> True 

Cython check avoided.   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "setup.py", line 353, in <module>    
    import kivy 
ImportError: No module named kivy
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/zeak/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/kivy-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/kivy && /home/zeak/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/py2048/bin/python.host setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/zeak/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/py2048/bin/python.host failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=py2048 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/zeak/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code you're running in addition to the error.

Comment: Are you sure that you have kivy installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Is kivy installed on your machine? Have you added kivy in requirements of buildozer.spec file?
If no then open the buildozer.spec file and in requirements add all the requirements

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Check if kivy is installed (pip install kivy). And in buildozer.spec add “requirements=kivy”.